# Viewing Y axis minimum value in negative

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

We are using the **jQuery flot** for viewing the graph in our webpages. The graph is viewing fine based on the X and Y axis values. But minimum value of the Y axis is taking "0" even if i'm giving the negative values. I want to give the Y axis value from -2500 to 13000 but it is starting from "0" only.Here is my script

```
yaxis: {
    min: -2500,
    max: 101339237
},
xaxis: {
    mode: "time",
    minTickSize: [1, "hour"],
    min: Xmin,
    max: Xmax,
    twelveHourClock: false
},
```

Can anyone please explain me how to view the Y-axis minimum value in negative. Is that possible in **jQuery flot?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of logarithmically scaled y-axis with a `transform` function:

http://jsfiddle.net/A24Vt/86/

Altenatively, try to reduce your `max` value which is orders of magnitude greater than -2500, this is why the negative values cannot be seen.

For instance like:

```
max: 10000
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but my maximum value also too large there is no possibilities to viewing this range instead of changing the max values

Comment: Okay then you need to scale the axes logarithmically -- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160446/logarithmic-chart-in-flot