# Equidistant Exponential Tick Scale JQuery Flot

Tags: jquery, charts, flot

I am trying to make a jQuery Flot bar graph with an exponential scale for the Y axis.

Currently I set the Y-Axis ticks to be equal to:

```
yticks = [];
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    yticks.push(Math.pow(10,i));
}
```

This adds the correct Y-Axis ticks, but the visual distance between the ticks is exponential with each proceeding tick (it's not equal distance).

I am looking to achieve something visually similar to Excel. The ticks are exponentially rising, but the difference between them is the same:

[image: Exponential Graph Excel]

Comment: Check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160446/logarithmic-chart-in-flot

Comment: Adding a transform function: function (v) { return Math.pow(v) } did not work for me.

Comment: Oh woops! I realize that you have to add both the ticks AND the transform function. Awesome I got it!