# Flot logarithmic and dynamic y-axis ticks

Tags: javascript, charts, flot, logarithm

I use flot for my charts and I need a logarithmic scale for my Y-Axis.
The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160446/logarithmic-chart-in-flot) is almost what I want, except that the Y-Axis has predefined ticks. This leads to charts that use only half or even less the height of the Y-Axis because I always have to define all ticks also for big values in case the chart contains big values.

If I don't define the ticks I get dynamic ticks which always fit the biggest values perfectly, but then the y-Axis tick lines are like on logarithmic paper (different distances between them), which I don't want.

I want ticks on every power of 10 (10,100,1000,10000 etc) but adapting to the biggest value in the chart, so there is no empty space above the biggest value.

Of course I can caluclate the maximum value in the chart by myself and adapt the ticks accordingly, but if there is a flot-solution, I would be happy to use it.

Thanks!s

Comment: Please don't post links to sites requiring registration to show something.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Changed the URL. Thanks for the hint, I pasted the wrong one before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no build in functionality for that.

If you only want powers of ten as ticks on your y-axis you have to calculate the minimum and maximum power of ten you want to use and then build a tick array from them.